# .htaccess url rewriting with php

Tags: php, .htaccess

I currently have an entire website running on PHP & GET variables.

My links look like this at present

```
 http://www.example.co.uk/brochure.php?cat_path=24
```

And occasionally it has a second variable in the url...

I actually would like my URLs to look like this:
    http://www.example.co.uk/Concrete_Fence_Posts

So my questions is simply, how do I go about rewriting urls without breaking my GET variables.

Thanks.

Comment: How are you currently rewriting the URLs?

Comment: I'm not currently rewriting at all :( My site is pretty well optimized for Search Engines, I'd just like to enhance it slightly with product names in the URL. Thanks

Comment: In what format do you want your URLs to be? Show an example. This format you have mentioned is the default one of PHP-apache and needs no rewrite rules for any number of GET variables. URLs won't break

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your parameters are always named `cat_path` and `product_id` (if it exists) you can do something like this:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([\d+])$         $1.php?cat_path=$2
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([\d+])/([\d+])$ $1.php?cat_path=$2&product_id=$3
```

Your URLs would then be in one of these formats:

```
pagename/cat_path
pagename/cat_path/product_id
```

For example:

```
http://www.bentinckfencing.co.uk/brochure/24
http://www.bentinckfencing.co.uk/product/35/54
```

**Edit:** I see you want to use product names in the URL. In that case, your PHP scripts will need to be able to take a name as a parameter and look up the ID. You should continue to accept the ID directly so as to not break existing links. Then your rewrite rule would look like this:

```
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$         brochure.php?name=$1
```

And http://www.bentinckfencing.co.uk/Concrete_Fence_Posts would rewrite to http://www.bentinckfencing.co.uk/brochure.php?name=Concrete_Fence_Posts.

Answer (score -1):

For better search search engine optimisation have URLs like stackoverflow -

```
http://www.bentinckfencing.co.uk/brochure/24/concrete-fence-posts
```

There is something like search engines do not store whatever is after the `?` in your URLs.
This ending `concrete-fence-posts` also helps users to identify the page in the browser address bar. But, you cannot allow certain special characters if the `?` is not used in the URL. Characters like `/`, `%` will break the URL and `\`, `#`, `+` will not appear.

**Updates**

Do you want to move completely from ID passing to name passing? I am not sure about how good that will be, but I have heard that a few well known sites have URLs like that. But, you may have to do many changes depending on your project (how many modules you have). The stackoverflow style URL will, however, retain the ID based item fetching.

**Further Updates**
You can try this rewrite rule to have both ID and name in the URL (stackoverflow style):-

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9\-\_]+)/([0-9]+)/([a-z0-9\-\_]+)/?$ $1.php?cat_path=$1&cat_name=$2
```

I have not tested it though.

Another important thing, I see that your code enters `brochure.php` directly and there is no common file (common controller) which is executed in case of all the modules. This approach can have many drawbacks, particularly if your's is a medium to large application. It is always better to execute a common `index.php` file and include the needed `brochure.php` file there so that you can perform all those common logics (needed in all your modules) in this `index.php` file. I have a common index.php file and the following rewrite rules do the same:-

```
############To remove display of "index.php" from URL
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [L,QSA]
#################################################end of hiding index.php

RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9\-\_]+)/([0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9\-\_]+)/?$ index.php?a=$1&b=$2&c=$3
```

**Note:-** The first block of rewrite rules hides the index.php from the URL and a visitor does not know that my application runs in PHP.

Finally I have URLs like this:-

```
http://www.bentinckfencing.co.uk/brochure/24/concrete-fence-posts
```

Hope this helps,
Sandeepan

Comment: This sounds like a perfect solution, as I'd like to stick with fetching results via ID, not Name. I can figure out how to get the name into the url (with another GET variable), but I'm not sure how I'd actually go about the rewrite. What code do I need for this?

Comment: @shane, check my Further Updates section

Comment: Col. Shrapnel downvoted me, I am 99% sure. Didn't even dare to write a comment. haha