# URL Rewriting with MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, .htaccess

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [.htaccess url rewriting with php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3647617/htaccess-url-rewriting-with-php)

The homepage on my website has a number of users, listed. Each user has 'view profile' link that takes you to `www.mysite.com/user-profiles/profile.php?id=32`, the `id` being relevant to the user.

Is it possible to use URL Rewriting to find the name and surnamce of the user for that ID in the database and rewrite it too something like?

`www.mysite.com/user-profiles/john-a-doe`

Any help would be greatly appreciated...

Comment: Sure it IS possible, but please notice to use an UNIQUE (combinated)field from your table. For example, when you have 2 members what's name is `John a Doe` you have a problem.

Is there an unique field available? In that case i'm sure we can help you out.

Comment: The simplest way would be, at the top of the script, to check for $_GET['name'] and then get the id parameter and set $_GET['id']=$user['id']; so the rest would work as normal. But as Ronn0 states the name could be duplicated, best to add in some extra security like md5 of id too.

Answer (score 4):

I recommend doing it this way

Print URLs in the following format `mysite.com/user-profiles/(ID)/(NAME)` then use this to rewrite:

```
RewriteRule ^user-profiles/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /user-profiles/profile.php?id=$1&name=$2 [L]
```

then in your `profile.php` `SELECT` for `id` and `name`

Note: There are several ways to achieve what you want, but since you're using Full Name for `(NAME)` that's gonna cause a problem (noted by Ronn0) when two users (or more) have the same name, with what I've suggested you're able to eliminate that problem.

Comment: Although name is not required, as ID is all thats needed to get the user from the database, it does stop people from changing the id in the url to view someone else's details

Comment: @Waygood Your server side authentication should stop that. The URL should not determine whether I am able to view a page or not, I can just sit and guess URLs if that's the case.

Comment: Only if there are any server side authentication.

Comment: I agree with @DaveRandom, that's why it's important to do both, URL uniqueness (check for `name` AND `id`) and authorization check (not just authentication by the way) to check if the user has the permission to view that profile (or any page)

Comment: I do agree with you both, but I'm saying don't assume there is any security already in place. I've worked on major systems (I didn't create) where there was not even a thought about authentication. Great when they held personal pdf's of passports etc.. and payslips.